# Running node.js on google cloud, but error running with docker

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I tried following document to run node.js app on google cloud:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Node.js is running fine, but however if I run `gcloud preview app run app.yaml` I get....

```
    File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
  _run_file(__file__, globals())
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
  execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1020, in <module>
  main()
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1013, in main
  dev_server.start(options)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 810, in start
  self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 193, in start
  _module, port = self._create_module(module_configuration, port)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 278, in _create_module
  threadsafe_override=threadsafe_override)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1536, in __init__
  super(ManualScalingModule, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 555, in __init__
  self._module_configuration)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 259, in _create_instance_factory
  module_configuration=module_configuration)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/vm_runtime_factory.py", line 71, in __init__
  8 if runtime_config_getter().threadsafe else 1, 10)
File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 391, in _get_runtime_config
  raise ValueError('The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for '
ValueError: The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for custom runtimes
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.run) DevAppSever failed with error code [1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bug with the latest Google Cloud SDK version 0.9.65.

You can revert to Cloud SDK 0.9.64 with the following commands:

```
gcloud config set component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.64
gcloud components update
```

The next release should have the fix.

**To return to the current version of the SDK, run:**

```
gcloud config unset --scope=installation component_manager/fixed_sdk_version
gcloud components update
```

**Update for SDK version 0.9.82**

Docker is no longer required for Node.js apps. If no dependency on AppEngine specific APIs, the preferred way to run the app locally is:

```
npm install
npm start
```

Include the following in your app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
api_version: 1
```

Comment: Your solution worked. However, now I'm getting 503 error when running. I simply followed https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world#running_hello_world to run NodeJS application on Google cloud. If I do "npm start" it runs fine,,, however now I'm getting 503 error.

Comment: Getting 

    http: Hijack is incompatible with use of CloseNotifier

Comment: How can we released to have SDK fixed version? "You have configured your Cloud SDK installation to be fixed to version" when i try to update "gcloud componets update app"

Comment: I updated the answer to include the command to return to current version of the SDK.

Comment: This seems to still be an issue on Google Cloud SDK 0.9.67

Comment: Yes, I ran into this same error with version 0.9.67 and used the above steps to rollback to version 0.9.66.  I was then able to run the app without the error.  There is supposed to be big changes to the SDK in release 0.9.68.  Hoping that will resolve this issue.

Comment: Still seems to be an issue with current releases of the local dev server.

Comment: With SDK 0.9.82, the preferred way to run basic Node.js apps locally is npm start.  I updated the answer to reflect this update.