# Setting up app engine for dart, gcloud preview error

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, gcloud

I'm having a problem setting up app engine development for dart

I was using
OS X 10.10
Dart SDK 1.11.1
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.67

Heres the error:

```
WC-Johndoe:dartsample Johndoe$ gcloud preview app run app.yaml
Module [default] found in file [/Users/Johndoe/Repos/dartsample/app.yaml]
INFO: Looking for the Dockerfile in /Users/Johndoe/Repos/dartsample
INFO: Using Dockerfile found in /Users/Johndoe/Repos/dartsample
INFO     2015-07-03 21:31:15,783 devappserver2.py:762] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-07-03 21:31:16,009 api_server.py:204] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53927
INFO     2015-07-03 21:31:16,010 api_server.py:629] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2015-07-03 21:31:16,010 api_server.py:632] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1027, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1020, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 817, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 193, in start
    _module, port = self._create_module(module_configuration, port)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 278, in _create_module
    threadsafe_override=threadsafe_override)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1539, in __init__
    super(ManualScalingModule, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 558, in __init__
    self._module_configuration)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 259, in _create_instance_factory
    module_configuration=module_configuration)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/vm_runtime_factory.py", line 71, in __init__
    8 if runtime_config_getter().threadsafe else 1, 10)
  File "/Users/Johndoe/Library/Cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 394, in _get_runtime_config
    raise ValueError('The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for '
ValueError: The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for custom runtimes
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.run) DevAppSever failed with error code [1]
```

...........................................

Comment: since dart is a custom runtime, and the system tells you to use "--custom_entrypoint", did you try to run "gcloud preview app run app.yaml --custom_entrypoint"?

Comment: "unrecognized arguments: --custom_entrypoint"

Comment: mine also returns "unrecognized arguments: --custom_entrypoint"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/cloud/J6LsrVVdJ6o

Setting the GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME environment variable to 0 should fix this

```
$ export GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME=0
$ gcloud preview app run app.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945321/running-node-js-on-google-cloud-but-error-running-with-docker) shows an issue with recent versions of Google's cloud SDK. Until further updates, there will be issues with using some other SDKs such as dart.

As mentioned in the link, in order to work around the issue, dial back the version of your Google cloud SDK using the commands in your terminal:

```
gcloud config set component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.64
gcloud components update
```

Revert to the current version of the cloud sdk via:

```
gcloud config unset --scope=installation component_manager/fixed_sdk_version
gcloud components update
```

Comment: It works and seems like 0.9.65 also works, Thanks a alot!