# How to fix "`The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for custom runtimes`"?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, gcloud-node, managed-vm

I get this error on appengine when I run `gcloud preview app run app.yaml`:
`The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for custom runtimes`

My `app.yaml`looks like:

```
version: 0-1-1
runtime: custom
vm: true
api_version: 1
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: dynamic
```

My dockerfile is just:
`FROM google/nodejs-runtime`

I reinstalled `gcloud` to get the latest version, did something change in the yaml config for managed VMs? This makes it impossible for me to test my app.

Comment: There was an earlier bug with Google Cloud SDK version 0.9.65, but should have been fixed.  Can you verify what SDK version you have by running: gcloud version   Related question and workaround is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945321/running-node-js-on-google-cloud-but-error-running-with-docker

Comment: FYI - I am also seeing this error with Google Cloud SDK 0.9.67.  I'm checking for a workaround or fix.

Comment: Just to update, I rolled back to previous version 0.9.66 and no longer see the error.  I ran:  gcloud config set component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.66  -- To get back to latest, run: gcloud config unset component_manager/fixed_sdk_version

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me (don't forget to do `gcloud components update` after).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be a bug or setup issue with Google Cloud SDK version 0.9.67 causing this error.  As a temporary workaround, you can revert to previous SDK version, which is working, with the following commands:

```
gcloud config set component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.66
gcloud components update
```

To return to the current version of the SDK, run:

```
gcloud config unset component_manager/fixed_sdk_version
gcloud components update
```

This issue appeared a few versions ago and was addressed here:
[Running node.js on google cloud, but error running with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945321/running-node-js-on-google-cloud-but-error-running-with-docker/30947709#30947709)

Answer (score 4):

You can run `gcloud help preview app run` to show a man page describing the run command and its parameters. `--custom-entrypoint` is described as:

```
 --custom-entrypoint CUSTOM_ENTRYPOINT
    Specify an entrypoint for custom runtime modules. This is required when
    such modules are present. Include "{port}" in the string (without
    quotes) to pass the port number in as an argument. For instance:
    --custom_entrypoint="gunicorn -b localhost:{port} mymodule:application"
```

Note that the error message says `--custom_entrypoint`, with an underscore, but the parameter is `--customer_entrypoint`, with a dash. The correct name is `--custom-entrypoint` see: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=191

For a nodejs you should be able to use something like:

```
gcloud preview app run app.yaml --project=your-project-id --custom-entrypoint "node index.js {port}"
```

Depending on how you start your application. The port seems to also be available as the environment variable PORT so you don't need to use `{port}` if your app does not handle command line arguments.

I haven't been able to use `npm start` or other `npm run <script>` from the `--custom-entrypoint` however.

Answer (score 0):

Comment lines 391 to 397 in

google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py

```
#      if (self._module_configuration.effective_runtime == 'custom' and
#          os.environ.get('GAE_LOCAL_VM_RUNTIME') != '0'):
#        if not self._custom_config.custom_entrypoint:
#          raise ValueError('The --custom_entrypoint flag must be set for '
#                           'custom runtimes')
#        else:
#          runtime_config.custom_config.CopyFrom(self._custom_config)
```